# ERROR: Azure Logic App is throwing error to read Azure Blob Storage | Status 400 - The specifed resource name contains invalid characters

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

From logic App, I am trying to connect to Azure Blob Storage and "Get Blob Content Using Path".
Objective is to get the file from Blob storage and attach that in email.
File is an excel file. But it's giving the following error on that step.

Please note the file name has all lowercase, container name is also lowercase without any character.

But getting the error

```js
    {
      "status": 400,
      "message": "The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.\r\n clientRequestId: XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXX",
      "error": {
        "message": "The specifed resource name contains invalid characters."
      },
      "source": "azureblob-XXXXXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net"
   }
```

Please help me to resolve that step.

Comment: Can you share the exact URL?

Comment: Can you show the logic app screenshot of the blob path? From your description it should be no problem. Maybe some invisible characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Blob path** in logic app looks like `your-container-name/your-blob-name`.

You should not give the full URL like `http://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/your-container-name/your-blob-name`.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your error:

[image]

Please check this article and make sure the name is correct:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata

My path looks right, it seems only have the lowercase of file name and container name. But in fact, there is an invisible character in the characters. You can not see it, but it will cause error. I suggest you to copy Blob path in the logic app, and then print characters one by one. After that you should find the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have received this error too once I fixed the path with URI only. After correcting the container name (all lowercase, no special char), everything worked.