# How to change where azure storage emulator stores its files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azurite

I am attempting to debug an application that is comprised of several microservices. Part of the cross service messaging is carried out by storing information in azure blob storage by one service to be read by the other. For local testing we use Azure storage emulator.

Recently my AD logon had to be recreated by our IT team. My username has gone from , to <myname.COMPANYNAME> and since then Azure storage emulator has failed me.

Attempting to view all local blob storage results in an error "Unable to retrieve child resources." though I can can confirm that each container still exists manually. Hunting online suggests the problem is due to the period in my AD logon name (changing this is non trivial due to it needing to be done by another department)

```
Unable to retrieve child resources.

Details:
{
  "name": "RestError",
  "message": "The specifed resource name contains invalid 
characters.\nRequestId:b305591f-acf0-4e2e-8cc6-e3305fa18fab\nTime:2021-09-
```

My current thinking is to try and configure the emulator to not store its files in my user account but I have yet to find anywhere that this can be carried out - the config file mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119066/change-running-ip-of-azure-storage-emulator) doesn't appear to have what I need.

For this a successful answer would be guidance on how to relocate the storage explorer without IT having to create a new logon, or a workaround that will allow storage explorer and the services to retrieve my various blob stores.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this thread > [Azure Storage Emulator store data on specific path - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671111/azure-storage-emulator-store-data-on-specific-path) if it can help related to azure storage emulator.

> NOTE:
>
> The Azure Storage Emulator is now deprecated. Microsoft recommends
> that you use the [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite) emulator for local development with
> Azure Storage [Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#differences-between-the-storage-emulator-and-azure-storage)

Most cases change in Logon names doesn’t have affect on blob, but maybe in few cases due to name connected permissions or SID.

After changing the username, check if any permissions or roles assigned previously are given to that new one and make sure if DN  and SID are not modified,  to access resources or check all the configurations that have done previously that depend only on DN. The Storage Emulator supports only a single fixed account and a well-known authentication key.

1.Try to restart the emulator and check whenever tried with new port or any newconfiguration.
See this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393047/microsoft-azure-tools-port-conflict-with-existing-application/34396080#34396080)

2. The invalid characters in the error in most of the cases happens with container  name (all lowercase, no special characters) .
   Try to check once and refer below  threads for resolution possibilities,if it is container issue.

- [SO ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58642921/error-the-specifed-resource-name-contains-invalid-characters-errorcode-invali)
- [SO Ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057075/error-azure-logic-app-is-throwing-error-to-read-azure-blob-storage-status-400)

3. Storage Explorer has several options for how and where it can source the information needed to connect to your proxy. To change which option is being used, go to Settings (gear icon on the left vertical toolbar) > Application > Proxy. [Network Connections in Azure Storage Explorer | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-network#proxy-sources)